# accessing variables from another form using javascript

Tags: java, forms, jsp, dom

in my current  webpage (a JSP file which uses a form) i am interested in accessing variables that is autocalculated in the current webpage using a java class, from another form (also another JSP file) using javascript and DOM methods...is this possible?

Form A contains a link to Form B and i would like to put a javascript method in Form 2 to get variables/information in Form A.

EDIT 1: just updated...i'm trying at the moment to make context path URLs to each different web page and save them as strings in a database. And in the Form 2 webpage, i will retrieve the string URL context path of Form 1 from the database and then somehow try to access that...still figuring that part out..

EDIT 2: this is not involving Parent-Child window, but a relationship between 2 webpages that uses a FORM element

Comment: How do you intend to access the other page?

Comment: Is this supposed to be data that the user has typed into the form or default data? If the former, why not just submit the form and include it in the next page with Java?

Comment: Assuming you don't have two windows open, one with each page.  then no, even if you did, then I think you would have to assign that value of that var to an object to be able to reference.

Comment: If one window is a child of the other (opened with something like `window.open`) you could access the data via some Javascript.

Comment: yes you can say its a kind of default data, if its user data i would probably have used a servlet

Comment: cant you store the form data in a session?